# Average of array with two objects

Tags: c#, arrays, average

(I don't know if I should call them objects or elements, sorry if I typed the wrong name).

I have this array:

```
data[] readings;
```

If I want the value I use the following( i = some position):

```
readings[i].value;
```

And if I want the date:

```
readings[i].date;
```

How can I get the average of all `value` in `readings` using the average method?

Comment: Duplicate: [how to average a array input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527032/c-sharp-how-to-average-a-array-input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use linq for this, something along the lines of

```
var average = readings.Average(r => r.value);
```

Note:  Average Computes the average of a sequence of numeric values.
MSDN Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average.aspx

Comment: Yes I tried this a few minutes ago but it didnt' work, it needs a cast because it says it can't convert object to float. So I did this and now it works: `readings.Average(r => Convert.ToDouble(r.value));`

Comment: @sparcopt Ah, cool, wasn't sure what the type was, but I am glad it worked out! I'll update the answer

Answer (score 1):

If `data.value` is a numeric type you can use Linq's [`Average`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average.aspx) extension method, like this:

```
var averageValue = readings.Average(d => d.value);
```

To get an average of a `DateTime`, you can do the same thing if you the date to clock ticks first:

```
var averageDate = new DateTime((long)readings.Average(d => d.date.Ticks));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a Linq query:

```
readings.Select(r => r.value).ToList().Average();
```